# URI::InvalidURIError on rails routing redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, invalid-url

in my routes.rb I have the follow route:

```
get '/merchandises/:cat/:id' => redirect('/products/%{id}')
```

This redirect work, but if the param id contain some character I get the error like this example:

```
Started GET "/merchandises/perfumes/Drakkar%20Noir%20Eau%20De%20Toilette" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-07 23:21:28 +0100

URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): /products/Drakkar Noir Eau De Toilette)
```

Someone can tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution:

```
get '/merchandises/:cat/:id' => redirect { |params, req| "/products/#{URI.escape(params[:id])}" }
```